# Flutter: ListView.builder ignores BoxContrainst of Container child. Always applies full parent width

Tags: flutter

Building chat bubbles in a chat app. I am unable to control the width of ListView.builder's Container children. The child Containers always take the full width of the ListView.builders parent: 
Expanded -> Container width.

What I'm trying to achieve: message bubble width as small as possible while still containing message text, but not larger than 75% of the screen width.

Ignore wrapping of text for this simplified example.

Where and why is the chatBubble getting this full screen width?

Super Simplified widget layout example:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    height: safeHeight,
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: messages.length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => chatBubble(messages[i]),
          )
        ),
        Container(
          height: 50,
          child: TextField(/* stuff */),
        )
      ]
    )
  );
}

chatBubble(Message msg) {
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
      child: Text(msg.text),
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxWidth: screenWidth * 0.75,
      ),
    )
  )
}
```

RESULT:
[image]

Comment: Try to put wrap `chatBubble()` response by `Column` widget with `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default all the widgets inside a `ListView` are expanded, but you can use other widget to keep your content wrapped. If you will have more data in your `chatBubble` you can use a `Column` or a `Wrap` widget as follows:

```
  chatBubble(Message msg) {
    return Wrap(
      children: [
       Padding(
        ...
        ),
       ],
    );
  }
```

But if you want to provide only one child in that section you can use an [Align Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html), which lets you use an `alignment property` to decide how to align the child. In this case, try the next:

```
 chatBubble(Message msg) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ...
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: you guys are my heros!